# how can create and update in the same method in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need help with creating a register and updating in other table in the same method. I have this code in my view `create.blade.php`:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="copropietario_id">seleccione departamento que paga</label>
         {!! Form::select('copropietario_id', $copropietario, null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione un departamento','required','id'=>'copropietario_id']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="totalmes">Deuda total del departamento</label>
         <input type="number" name="totalmes" id="totalmes" readonly value="{{ old('id') }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="fecha">Ingresar Fecha de Ingreso</label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha" value="{{ date('Y') }} " class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha del ingreso">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="monto">Ingresar Monto del Pago</label>
         <input type="number" name="monto" id="monto" required value="{{ old('monto') }}" onkeyup="calculate(this.value);" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el monto del pago...">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="deuda">Saldo pendiente</label>
         <input type="number" readonly name="deuda" id="deuda" value="{{ old('deuda') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="Total de la deuda...">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to save this request in a table `ingresos`, which works until here. The problem now is that I need to update 2 values `monto` and `deuda` in another table `morosos`, the same values created in `ingresos`, but need update in `morosos`.

```
public function store(ComprobanteIngresoFormRequest $request, $copropietario_id){
  $Ingresos= new ComprobanteIngreso;

  $Ingresos->cliente_id=$request->get('cliente_id');
  $Ingresos->copropietario_id=$request->get('copropietario_id');
  $Ingresos->fecha=$request->get('fecha');
  $Ingresos->formapago=$request->get('formapago');
  $Ingresos->monto=$request->get('monto');
  $Ingresos->fondos=$request->get('fondos');
  $Ingresos->nulo=$request->get('nulo');
  $Ingresos->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
  $Ingresos->cheque=$request->get('cheque');
  $Ingresos->banco=$request->get('banco');
  $Ingresos->deuda=$request->get('deuda');

  //$Ingresos->save();

  $Morosos= Morosos::findOrFail($copropietario_id);
  $Morosos->montopago = $request->get('monto');
  $Morosos->totalmoroso = $request->get('deuda');

  dd($Ingresos, $Morosos);
  $Morosos->update();

  return Redirect::to('admin/ingresos');
}
```

The update will be in `morosos` where `copropietario_id` is the same that I select or the same `copropietario_id` when I create a new `ingresos`

Comment: Not sure I follow what the issue is here. But, try with `$Morosos->save();` instead of `$Morosos->update();`. `$model->save()` generally the go-to function after modifying  properties of `$model` (like `$model->montopago = ...;`)

Comment: And why not `$Ingresos = new ComprobanteIngreso($request->all());`?

Comment: `update` is just `fill(...)->save()` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premises:
You are creating a new `Ingreso`, and updating a existing `Moroso`.

My suggestion is:

```
public function store(ComprobanteIngresoFormRequest $request, $copropietario_id){
  $Ingresos= new ComprobanteIngreso;

  $Ingresos->cliente_id=$request->get('cliente_id');
  $Ingresos->copropietario_id=$request->get('copropietario_id');
  $Ingresos->fecha=$request->get('fecha');
  $Ingresos->formapago=$request->get('formapago');
  $Ingresos->monto=$request->get('monto');
  $Ingresos->fondos=$request->get('fondos');
  $Ingresos->nulo=$request->get('nulo');
  $Ingresos->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
  $Ingresos->cheque=$request->get('cheque');
  $Ingresos->banco=$request->get('banco');
  $Ingresos->deuda=$request->get('deuda');

  $Ingresos->save();
  $Ingresos->refresh();

  $Morosos= Morosos::findOrFail($copropietario_id);
  $Morosos->montopago = $Ingresos->monto;
  $Morosos->totalmoroso = $Ingresos->deuda;

  // Update the 'updated_at' field
  $Moroso->updated_at = now();

  // This save the changes in Moroso table
  $Morosos->save();

  return Redirect::to('admin/ingresos');
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solved this. I can suggested the following approach:

```
function store(ComprobanteIngresoFormRequest $request, $copropietario_id)
{
    $Ingresos = ComprobanteIngreso::create($request->all());
    // This is assuming you're passing $copropietario_id as id of Morosos
    $Morosos = Morosos::findOrFail($copropietario_id);
    $Morosos->update([
        'montopago'   => $Ingresos->monto,
        'totalmoroso' => $Ingresos->deuda,
    ]);

    return Redirect::to('admin/ingresos');
}
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First use camel case for your variables

```
public function store(ComprobanteIngresoFormRequest $request, $copropietario_id){
  $ingresos= new ComprobanteIngreso;

  $ingresos->cliente_id=$request->get('cliente_id');
  $ingresos->copropietario_id=$request->get('copropietario_id');
  $ingresos->fecha=$request->get('fecha');
  $ingresos->formapago=$request->get('formapago');
  $ingresos->monto=$request->get('monto');
  $ingresos->fondos=$request->get('fondos');
  $ingresos->nulo=$request->get('nulo');
  $ingresos->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
  $ingresos->cheque=$request->get('cheque');
  $ingresos->banco=$request->get('banco');
  $ingresos->deuda=$request->get('deuda');

  $ingresos->save();

  $morosos= Morosos::findOrFail($copropietario_id);
  $morosos->montopago = $request->get('monto');
  $morosos->totalmoroso = $request->get('deuda');

  $morosos->save();

  return Redirect::to('admin/ingresos');
}
```

Comment: It's a recommended practice on PSR, however all depends how is the code style define on their project.